# How to return a value from event listener function in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having difficulty returning a value from an event listener function and storing it in a variable.

What I did is as below, but I can not do this and I have no idea how to solve the problem.

```js
$(".container").click(function() {
  let color = $(".container").css("background-color");

  //I want to return this color and store it in a variable.
})
```

```css
.container {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to do, you are already storing the color in a variable in this line `let color = $(".container").css("background-color");`

Comment: maybe OP wants to store that in a global variable

Comment: I'm assuming from the context that you want to use the `color` variable *outside* of the `click` event handler? If so, you need to create a new function with the required logic and pass `color` in to that as an argument. You can't return a value from an event handler.

Comment: What I want to do is      let newColor = $(".container").click(function(){ let color = $(".container).css("background-color"); return color)}

Comment: Given than you use just `$(".container").css` and not `$(this).css` then just make that call when/where you need it.  If you use it more than once, then make it a function.  Unless this is a *derived example* (ie not the actual code) - in which case the actual code may be more complicated - as is, there's no need to set this only on click.

Comment: *What I want...* - that's not possible as the event will occur later on, after the let color= line has run.   You can move the `let` to outside, eg  `let color = ""; $(".container").click(() => color = $(".container"...` then the `color` variable will be *available* outside, but won't be set until the user clicks.   It depends on what you want to do with that variable - if you want to know when it changes (ie when the user clicks) then just put your code that uses it inside the event handler (or call a function from the event handler ofc)

Comment: Your code should not have problem. I did one and you could check whether it is what you want: https://codepen.io/CrescentLee/pen/yLjpoaX

Comment: Why to `return`  color from the event handler `.click(function()..`? Can rest of the requirement also be coded within in the event handler itself?

Answer (score -1):

I think this is what you are looking for

```
var container = document.getElementById("myDivID")
var containerColor = window.getComputedStyle(container).backgroundColor;
```

Now you can return it via an alert or inserting it as html into another div.

Comment: How does this help OP with storing it on a click?

Comment: @cloned As far as I understand what OP wants to do, I'm saving in a variable the hex code of the colow of the "container" div